# Woocommerce aJax apply coupon code to basket

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to apply a coupon code to the basket on a button press.
I have the following code:-

```
coupon = jQuery(this).data('coupon');
data = {coupon_code : coupon};
jQuery.post( "?wc-ajax=apply-coupon", { coupon_code: coupon }).done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

I can see the following data is being parsed to the server:-

```
coupon_code: 10percentdiscount
```

The `10percentdiscount` exists.

The Server is not sending back a response once I have sent the request.

Am I correctly making this request or is there another way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do so:

Define ajax url in header.php or in page would you add coupon

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var ajax_url = "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
</script>
```

In function.php you must define ajax call

```
function implement_ajax() {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/ajax_return.php');
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_action', 'implement_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_action', 'implement_ajax');
```

In ajax_return.php you past code that add coupon to woocommerce:

```
if (isset($_POST['couponcode']))
    { apply_coupon($_POST['couponcode']); }; 

function apply_coupon($couponcode) { 
    global $woocommerce; WC()->cart->remove_coupons();
    $ret = WC()->cart->add_discount( $couponcode ); 
    $array = array('return' => $ret); print_r($array); 
}
exit;
```

Your jQuery.post will became this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    coupon = jQuery(this).data('coupon');
    jQuery.post(ajax_url, {action : 'my_special_action', couponcode : coupon}, return_function, 'JSON');
});

function return_function(data)
{
   console.log(data.return); //contains true if coupon was applied
}
</script>
```

If you need, call return_function to manage response.

Comment: I have implemented your code, when I used the code you have above I got return_function not defined. I altered your code and the the server has responded with a 0 and the coupon code has not been added.

Comment: Is there no way I can do this using ?wc-ajax=apply_coupon. I have noticed that a security key needs to be defined, does anybody know how it generates the key?

Comment: I don't know if exist a way to using wp-ajax but I suggest you tu use the correct way to make an ajax call with wordpress.

ps: i've update code correctly. so, if you have problems on return_function, simply declare it:
function return_function(data)
{
  console.log(data);
}

Comment: Why have you changed it to create a coupon? I am trying to apply a coupon on a button click via ajax that already exists.

Comment: sorry, I believed you want add instead of apply. I've fixed code already. In return_function you manage true/false response

Comment: I have added your code, and fixed the following line $ret = $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $get1 ); -> $ret = $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $couponcode ); and fixed couponcode : coupon -> coupon_code : coupon but the server is still returning a 0 value. I dont get a true of false value.

Comment: Try to call data.return in return_function, Furthermore add exit; to the end of ajax_return.php page

Comment: This is returning undefined

Comment: I've fixed code anymore: ajax_return.php in particular. Test for last time :)

Comment: The server is kicking back a 500 error on the request now.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the ajax_return.php to:-  

<?php

if (isset($_POST['couponcode'])) {
 apply_coupon($_POST['couponcode']);
};

function apply_coupon($couponcode) {
    global $woocommerce;

    WC()->cart->remove_coupons();

    $ret = WC()->cart->add_discount( $couponcode );

    $array = array('return' => $ret);

    print_r($array);

}

exit;


Update you answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Of course! I've update code. That's a good example of pair programming ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to add custom code in your functions.php. Woocommerce supports adding coupons via AJAX natively (see how below).

**Errors in your code:**

1. You forgot to send the nonce (security parameter);
2. It is `apply_coupon` not `apply-coupon` (underscore vs dash);
3. Your URL should start with a slash "**/**?wc-ajax=apply_coupon";

**Correct version:**

```
var data = {
  coupon_code: jQuery(this).data('coupon'), 
  security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("apply-coupon") ?>'
};
jQuery.post('/?wc-ajax=apply_coupon', data).done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Comment: A note with this method is that if you need to check whether a coupon was applied or not with WC()->cart->applied_coupons, it'll return empty unless user is either logged in or has items in cart.

Comment: this code is returning 403 error