# Ajax remove coupon from mini-cart WooCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I am using the `mini-cart.php` file and the cart `widget` to show cart content and I am using `AJAX` `add to cart` standard built in `WooCommerce`.
Adding products to my cart works fine. I added an area to show if any `coupon` is added (see my code). Works all fine but when deleting the coupon I want it to be done without loading a next page. It only needs to update the `mini-cart.php`. Can someone help me? Basically I need some `function` or something which updates `mini-cart.php` without reloading the page.

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
    <p>Actieve kortingscode: <?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?></p>
    <p><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Working https://youtu.be/M2qmiQ8v9tw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the answer to your question in WooCommerce documentation

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html

The short answer is you need to make a call to WC()->cart->remove_coupons();

As of the "how", check this SO answer (different thing but same way to resolve it)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41593818/10864482