# Woocommerce ajax coupon link

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created coupon links for Woocommerce with this:

```
function coupon_links()
{
    if (!function_exists('WC') || !WC()->session) {
        return;
    }   

    $query_var = apply_filters('woocommerce_coupon_links_query_var', 'coupon');
    if (empty($_GET[$query_var])) {
        return;
    }

    WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
    if (!WC()->cart->has_discount($_GET[$query_var])) {
        WC()->cart->add_discount($_GET[$query_var]);
    }
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'coupon_links', 30);
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'coupon_links');
```

I need this in order to auto-apply a specific coupon when the user clicks on a link on the cart page. While it works, it is not ajax loaded. How can I make this link ajax so that the cart page does not refresh, but instead just ajax load like when you remove a coupon?

Comment: @Sergey Ligus your link does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Redo the comment, sorry ) Have you looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593442/woocommerce-ajax-apply-coupon-code-to-basket/41593818#answer-41593818) for example @fredrik

Comment: @Sergey Ligus my PHP knowledge is limited...I thought I could somehow make the above code create an ajax link?

Comment: You can triger with following woo ajax events - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend i think checking if its cart page and event is wc_fragments_loaded will do the trick.

Comment: @Martin Mirchev my PHP is limited...could you help me with that?